# Trying to make tags using collection view

Tags: swift

Im trying to make this collectionView but programmatically:

https://github.com/shamiul110107/TagView-in-swift

[TagView screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0g9W.png)

This is my custom cell and View controller:

```
  import UIKit

 class TagCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    self.backgroundColor = .black
// self.layer.cornerCurve = 8.0 NOT WORKING
    sportLabel.clipsToBounds = true
    sportLabel.textAlignment = .center
    
    contentView.addSubview(sportLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(deleteButton)
    
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        sportLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
        sportLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
        sportLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
        
        deleteButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
        deleteButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
        deleteButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sportLabel.trailingAnchor),
        deleteButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
        
    ])
}


lazy var sportLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    label.textColor = .white
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

lazy var deleteButton : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "trash.circle.fill")?.withTintColor(UIColor.red), for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.backgroundColor = .red
    return button
}()

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError()
}

 }
```

ViewController:

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let arr = ["Ada","Belgrade","San Francisco"]

lazy var collectionView :UICollectionView = {
     let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 40, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero,collectionViewLayout: layout)
    
    cv.collectionViewLayout = layout
     cv.delegate = self
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.register(TagCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "trainingCell")
    cv.backgroundColor = .blue
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     return cv
   
}()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    

    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor,constant: 0),
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor,constant: 10),
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor,constant: -10),
        collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.heightAnchor,multiplier: 1/3)
    
    ])
    
}


 }
  extension ViewController:  UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfSections section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arr.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "trainingCell", for: indexPath) as! TagCollectionViewCell
    cell.sportLabel.text = arr[indexPath.row]
    
    return cell
}


}
```

All I was able to make is this:

[MyTagView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ipn4H.png)

**I don't know why cells overlapping and why Im not able to add corner radius.**

Edit: When minimumInteritemSpacing = 50

[minimumInteritemSpacing Changed to 50](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88Ivr.png)

My solution I don't know is it best solution but it works somehow :

To get rounded cells add to TagCollectionViewCell override init  this:

```
   contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
    contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    sportLabel.clipsToBounds = true
    
    
    deleteButton.clipsToBounds = true
```

My solution for cell size was this. I have to mention that  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 23) was best in my case:

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

```
    return  CGSize(width: arr[indexPath.row].size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 23)]).width + 40, height: 40)
    }
```

I had to add + 40 to width because I have button inside cell also that has fixed width = 30 so + 40 fits best.

[With all modifications above it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFZTE.png)

Comment: What if you tried increasing the `minimumInteritemSpacing` to 5 or 10, this should increase the spacing between the cells. Change `self.layer.cornerCurve` to `self.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0` and this should give you rounded corners. Try and let me know.

Comment: minimumInteritemSpacing is working when its on 50 because only then i have spacing between all cells. If I try with 20 only cell with shotest label gets some spacing("Ada" in my case) and longer label cell still overlaps until minimumInteritemSpacing = 50. I don' know why. Unfortunately self.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0 doesn't work either @ShawnFrank

Comment: If you still did not find a solution, I will look deeper into this tomorrow morning.

Comment: I've found some solution by myself should I post it? Or first edit post with my solution so you can review it @ShawnFrank

Comment: if your solution completely works for you, then you can post it as an answer so others can benefit from your research and experience. If your problem is not fully solved, just add to your question with what you have changed and what is the result till now and what is still not yet solved and one of us will see if we can help.

Answer (score 0):

My solution I don't know is it best solution but it works somehow :

To get rounded cells add to TagCollectionViewCell override init this:

```
contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
sportLabel.clipsToBounds = true
deleteButton.clipsToBounds = true
```

My solution for cell size was this. I have to mention that UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 23) was best in my case:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

return  CGSize(width: arr[indexPath.row].size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 23)]).width + 40, height: 40)
}
```

I had to add + 40 to width because I have button inside cell also that has fixed width = 30 so + 40 fits best.

[image: How it looks now]